# Can I initialize a std::vector with '=' thanks to the operator overloading?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization, operator-overloading

I noticed that in C++11 I can initialize a vector in the following ways(not only these):

```
std::vector<int> v1{0,1,2};
std::vector<int> v2={3,4,5};
```

I suppose that in the first line the following constructor is used:

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

My doubt is whether the second line uses the same constructor or the operator overloading of '=' is involved.

Here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization, it says that

```
T object = {arg1, arg2, ...};
```

is considered as an initializer_list, right? In this case the overloading of '=' shouldn't be involved right?

Comment: Yes, this is list initialization, case #10 from the document that you linked.

Comment: Does it mean that the overloading of '=' is not involved?

Comment: @Christian Yes, it's not involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the same constructor is used to construct the object here.

`std::vector<int> v1{0,1,2};` is [direct list intialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#direct-list-initialization), while `std::vector<int> v2={3,4,5};` is [copy list intialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#copy-list-initialization), both are initialization, which means the appropriate constructor will be invoked to construct the `std::vector`. They're not assigment, then have nothing to do with the assignment operator (i.e. `operator=`).

On the other hand, this is assignment:

```
std::vector<int> v2; // default initialization
v2 = {3,4,5};        // this is assignment; 
                     // std::vector::operator=(std::initializer_list<T>) will be invoked
```